# How to increase touch target size for Android Toolbar Navigation Button?

Tags: android

I am extending Android Toolbar in my app and the touch target height for the navigation button is 24dp. How can I set minHeight and minWidth to 48dp? I have tried defining a custom style according to [this article](https://medium.com/@lucasurbas/making-android-toolbar-responsive-2627d4e07129):

```
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.Toolbar</item>
    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.Toolbar.Button.Navigation</item>
</style>
<style name="Custom.Widget.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="maxButtonHeight">48dp</item>
</style>
<style name="Custom.Widget.Toolbar.Button.Navigation" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
</style>
```

But as you can see it did not work (height is 24dp here according to Accessibility Scanner)

[image]

Comment: by using custom toolbar

Comment: What is the size of the drawable you're using for your navigation bar icon?

Comment: @ianhanniballake it is 24x24dp. I want to keep the visual size and have a 12dp border that extends the clickable space.

Comment: So why is your 12dp border not just as part of your icon?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using `R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material` from Android support library. I guess I could try doing a custom icon but would rather not.